# No 2D Image container in c++

Tags: c++

Why there is no standard image  (2d? 3d? Nd?) container in c++ std library? Although frequently used, there isn't anything in the horizon for such container, yet there are thousands of different implentation.

Stroustrup, where are you?

Comment: "Image" is a somewhat vague term. 24bit RGB image? 3D implies voxels in grayscale (for something like density). If a template class is desired, why not use `vector<vector<ColorType>>`? If you want to write specific formats, such as PNG, I don't see that as something that the standard library should do. Can you describe what the container should be able to do that a folded `std::vector` can't?

Comment: There are plenty of [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) in the Standard C++ Library. Take your pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The std::valarray class + std::gslice can be used for administrating 2D, 3D ... ND matrices.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/gslice

See some example in the link.

If your intention is the image manipulation refer to the specific specialized libraries (jpeg, png ....).

Comment: Valarray is nice but is not 2d array representation. My question is why there is no strictly Nd container in the std language

Comment: Normally and internally the implementations of the ND array are 1D arrays with an indexing procedure that calculate the offset. So the std::valarray + std::gslice are sufficient for administrating a simple ND array. For a more sophisticated implementation of the ND array it is better to search for a specialized numerical libs. . Normally an advanced implementation of an ND matrix is a bit sophisticated and specialized to the specific applications.